# Mathematica Support for Simulating Kirigami Cuts

Tags: graphics, dynamic

We can easily draw a grid like

```
  GraphPlot[GridGraph[{12, 12}], GraphLayout -> {"GridEmbedding", "Dimension" -> {12, 12}}]
```

This gives us

[image]

Does Mathematica have any capability to allow a user to select and then stretch parts of this image and simulate  [*Kirigami Cuts*](https://phys.org/news/2019-08-mathematical-framework-sheet-material-kirigami.html)?